# string causes a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Visual C++ found memory leaks in my code so I whittled it down to as simplest test case as I could and got this:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC   // required
#include <stdlib.h>         // to enable MSVC++
#include <crtdbg.h>         // memory leak detection

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string foo;

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{130} normal block at 0x008748A8, 8 bytes long.
 Data:  B4 F9 44 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

If I comment out "string foo;" it doesn't detect anything.

Should I be deallocating foo somehow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're running `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` too early and it reports the `string` body as a leak. Only run it after all the local objects could have been destroyed.

Either wrap all meaningful work in a separate function

```
void  doStuff()
{
    string variable;
}
```

or  add nested scope:

```
int main()
{
    {
       string variable;
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which obviously is impossible if you have any stack-based objects!  `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` is from the *C* runtime library; it wasn't anticipating destructors...

Comment: @Oli: Impossible how? sharptooth demonstrated how to do it.

Comment: Now I feel silly for wasting so much time trying to figure out what I was doing wrong and for asking what turned out to be a dumb question. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Tomalak: True, but it involves messing with your program structure.  Also, if you have any static/global strings, this won't help...

Comment: @Oli: Indeed, there are caveats.

Comment: While you are at it put in the try catch block to make sure that stack is unwound in all situations.

Answer (score 10):

You should call _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks after program/block termination. The best way to do that is have
CRT call that itself upon program termination, as stated in the [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/d41t22sb(v=VS.90).aspx):

> _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks is frequently called at the end of program execution
>   to verify that all memory allocated by
>   the application has been freed. The
>   function can be called automatically
>   at program termination by turning on
>   the _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF bit field of
>   the _crtDbgFlag flag using the
>   _CrtSetDbgFlag function.

By calling it the way you did, it will detect the  foo as a leak since it's destructor
hasn't yet been called since the execution block hasn't ended yet.

Comment: Just to clarify @Shinnok's answer: don't call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` directly, instead have it called automatically by adding this line to your program: `_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );`

Comment: @GrahamS that fixed my problem if random leaks :P thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` while the string still exists - of course it detects that the string still exists!

Try this:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC   // required
#include <stdlib.h>         // to enable MSVC++
#include <crtdbg.h>         // memory leak detection

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    {    
      string foo;
    }

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    return 0;
}
```